# My Trackpoint stops working until I turn off and on the computer

Tags: troubleshooting, services, lenovo-laptop, trackpoint

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad with a Trackpoint. I find that sometimes the Trackpoint will just stop working. This is fixed by quickly pressing the power button (to put the computer to sleep) and then waking up the computer. I was hoping there was a service or process that I could just restart, but I didn't find any information on this and I tried restarting various services, but it did not solve the problem.

This may be related to hardware since it seems that this primarily happens when I put pressure on the laptop a certain way. I.e. if I'm lying down and my leg is under the middle of the laptop. I will have to go through the process I described to get the Trackpoint back.

Would there be a way to get my Trackpoint back without putting my computer to sleep?

Comment: Are you running the latest driver from the Lenovo website?

Comment: @Steven Indeed I am.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a known problem that Lenovo still has not fixed. The community created a workaround available here:
https://broken-trackpoint.com/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).